# What happens to running Java processes if I install a new version of the JDK?

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I am wondering what happens with running Java processes if I update the JDK on a Debian machine. The answer is probably the same for other systems as well, I just wanted to be more explicit about my environment.

With update I mean that the newer JDK will be installed next to the existing one, and the symlink `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` will be changed to the folder of the new JDK.

Folder structure after the update:

- `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` -> `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79`
- `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21  # old version`
- `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79  # new version`

Will the running processes be affected by this change?

Answer (score 6):

The running processes are running off of the real JVM executable, not off of the symbolic link.

So, they will continue to run, but they will not switch over to the new JVM version you've just installed until you restart them.

Comment: I was rather worried about the running JVM trying to load libraries or config files at run time and not finding these anymore due to the changed sym link.

Comment: @MichaelKüller Understandable. Don't worry, they're already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

We run into a huge problems after an JDK update:

The update has been automatically installed with `yum-cron` (CentOS). But it has deleted the old JDK installation (1.8.0.382 -> 1.8.0.392). There were more than 100 JVMs running with the older version on the server. The update deleted the executables and the standard JARs. So the JVMs run but if they need a new class from the deleted JARs (loaded by class loader), they will throw exceptions:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.382.b05-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar:java.lang.InternalError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.382.b05-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar
```

A lot of functionality was not longer available till a restart of the JVMs. We have found all affected processes with

```
ls -alF /proc/*/exe | grep java | grep "1.8.0.382" 1>processIds.log
```

It is better to exclude Java from automatically updates.